# Wordpress category permalink

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks, slug

I have a wordpress based website and the default category permalink is like "website.com/category/category-slug"

How can I make it look like "website.com/category-slug"? Of course I will always take care that there is no post/page with the same slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, although not tested. Fill in the categoryID below and set your desired URL in wp_redirect().

```
<?php
$category_id = xx;
$category_link = get_category_link( $category_id )
wp_redirect( $category_link, 'http://www.website.com/category-slug' ); exit;
?>
```

Remember by the way that wp_redirect() always should be followed by `exit;` (Source: [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)).

Comment: Are you sure that this works as a rewrite rule? I don't just want to redirect the page to another URL, so that it ends up looking like "website.com/category/slug" but I want it to BE "website.com/slug" when you load the page. And where am I supposed to add this lines?

Comment: Well, actually, Mustafa Ehsans solution 1 seems like the better one. I'd go with that.

Comment: But can I do that without Step 1? I don't wanna change the single post permalink, I want both single posts and categories look like "website.com/slug"

Comment: After doing a little more research it seems like a plugin might be the best way to go. You could also download it, pick out the pieces you want, and put them i functions.php. But that might be a little time consuming. Anyway, this seems like a good plugin - and its supported; https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions for it:

### Solution 1 (simple one):

For removing **/category/** from the URLs, do as follow:

**Step 1**: Go to **Settings > Permalinks**, select **Custom Structure** and enter the following into textbox:

[image]

**Step 2**: In **Category Base** enter **/** as follow:

[image]

**Step 3**: Save it and your URLs will be http://website.com/category-slug.

---

### Solution 2:

Although not updated for 2 years but a very flexible plugin. Simple install this plugin: [WP No Category Base](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/).

Comment: But this way the single post will look like "website.com/category-slug/post-slug" while I want them to show "website.com/post-slug" just as like the categories

Comment: Updated my answer with **solution 2**. See if that can help.

Comment: That's actually helpful but I'd prefer not to use any plugin and even if I did, I'd like to know how the plugin manages to do that, as it looks like a very small issue. And btw I only have two categories so the whole thing is quite static, I hoped it could have been done with one or two rewrite rules

Comment: Although this one is very old, I still have the same question. I would love to know if there are new solutions in all of these years.